# Simple array operation in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => b
        [1] => 8
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => c
        [1] => 16
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => d
        [1] => 21
    )
....

)
```

Numbers in inner array are generated randomly from range (0, 100) and they don't repeat.

I would like to create a loop, which will iterate from 0 to 100 and check if loop iteration is equal to inner number of above array. Excepted result is array with 100 elements:

```
Array
(
  [0] => const
  [1] => a
  [2] => const
  [3] => const
  [4] => const
  [5] => const
  [6] => const
  [7] => const
  [8] => b
  [9] => const
  [10] => const
  .
  .
  [16] => c
  [17] => const
  .
  .
  [21] => d
  [22] => const
  [23] => const
  .
  .
)
```

What I need is something like:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  if($i === $name[$i][1]) {
    $new_array[] = $name[$i][0];
  } else {
    $new_array[] = 'const';
  }
}
```

But I can't get it working, thus I need some help.

I am not an English native speaker, so hopefully you understand what I would like to achieve. Thanks for any help.

Comment: May I ask what's the output of your code?

Comment: What have you tried? [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map), [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter), [array_walk](http://www.php.net/array_walk),... the list goes on and on, depending on the desired output, pick one of _many_ array functions

Answer (score 1):

you need a nested loop like:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++):
   $found = false;
   foreach($name as $array):
      if($array[1] === $i):
         $found = true;
         $new_array[] = $array[0];
       endif;
   endforeach;
  if(!$found):
    $new_array[] = 'const';
  endif;
endfor;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because each time `$i` is incremented you're trying to make a match in `$name[$i]`, and not checking all of the arrays in `$name`, the simplest solution I can think of (and to perform the least number of iterations) would be to do something like:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($name as $n) {
  $new_array[$n[1]] = $n[0];
}

for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
  if (!isset($new_array[$i])) {
    $new_array[$i] = 'const';
  }
}
ksort($new_array);
```

So first of all, loop through your `$name` array, and set up your `$new_array` with the the `key` => `value` pair (eg. `[1] => 'a', [8] => 'b'`), then in the `for` loop just check if the `key  ($i)` has already been set, and if not, set it with the `value` 'const'. Finally, sort the `$new_array` by its keys.

The number of iterations in this example is `count($name) + 100`, whereas a nested loop for example would be `100 * count($name)`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
 if($i === $name[$i][1]) {
   $new_array[$i] = $name[$i][0];
  }
  else{
    $new_array[$i] = 'const';
  }
}
```

Comment: $new_array[] equals $new_array[$i] if keys are consecutive

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); ++$i) {
    if ($name[$i][1] === $i) {
        $name[$i] = $name[$i][0];
    } else {
        $name[$i] = 'const';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do u use `Identical` operator instead of `Equal`

```
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  if($i == $name[$i][1]) {
    $new_array[] = $name[$i][0];
  } else {
    $new_array[] = 'const';
  }
}
```